# Query-first approach for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql

I'm beginning to design a brand new MongoDB database for a project that will surely have a lot of concurrent access.
I'm choosing MongoDB for I know how scalable it is and how fast my queries will be.

I know, however, that even using MongoDB, for the sake of performance, I should try to hit the database as few times as possible.

I know that Apache Cassandra, another NoSQL database, advocates the "query-first" approach, which means you should think of your queries first, and then organize your data structures according to them.

Now, I'm wondering if the same principle applies to MongoDB.

I didn't find any related discussion about this on the web so far.

Comment: There are a lot of discussions on this, just search "mongodb query to schema design" on Google I got tonnes of results, however, yes generally you will want to form your schema around your queries

Comment: For any system where I care about performance regardless if it uses  SQL/NoSQL, I always consider the structure of the data and how it will be accessed or queried. How you structure your data within various DBs may be different and rules are applied differently, but I think it's an important aspect of any production software project.

Answer (score 1):

For organizing and modeling your data in Mongo, the word you want to learn and search on is *denormalization*. I would definitely think of your queries first when working with Mongo. Not just for modeling, but for indexing as well.

A good rule I heard at a Mongo conference for how to denormalize:

1. If the data is fairly static, go ahead and denormalize/embed the data in a document.
2. If the data changes quite often, make a reference to another document.

I've seen this to be very true after a year of production Mongo work. Embedding data that changes often has caused us a lot of pain.

Comment: Though it should be noted that de-normalisation IS NOT the only way to schema design and at times is not recommended. That paradigms strengths depends, once again, upon querying.

Answer (score 0):

Query first is important while working with MongoDB as you just can't store all your data "as is" and just create arbitrary queries and joins across tables (collections) latter. MonogDB is a document oriented database, ie. you always work with documents instead of result sets from different tables.

Good news is that MongoDB is schema less. You can structure your documents as you like and even change the schema of your documents over time as needed. But what you do need to think about beforehand is how (using what kind of key and index) and when (remember, you can't do joins!) you're going to retrieve them.

As ryan1234 suggested, denormalization is an option to deal with this. However, this can lead to redundant data and can become hard to maintain over time. So you probably don't want denormalize just everything. You need to be pragmatically address those short comings in your application code. Heres some suggestions for that:

- Prefetch frequently used data, such as lookup tables, as long as memory footprint is acceptable.
- Decide about what data needs to be available really fast on demand, e.g. by request on a web interface. Ideally you'll just have a single key that can be queried using an index which will serve you all data needed for a single request.
- Decide about what data can be handled in the background using long running jobs such as map reduce or queues. Or even have custom cronjob scheduled jobs that will do something with your data, e.g. preparing reports that you can retrieve later using an index.
- Do multiple requests and join data in your client. E.g. if you have a web client you can do several subsequent requests for pulling your data, which you probably would have done in a single request using a RDBMS. Queries in MongoDB are really fast if indexed, theres nothing wrong doing many requests per se as long you don't synchronize multiple queries and join data on the server. Doing this on the client allows you to leverage the whole stack (load balancer, caches,..) while progressively building the UI